# Gorilla session.AddFlash Does Not Add Flash Message

Tags: go, gorilla

I have a registration page with two handlers, one for displaying the form, one for processing a form submission.

I am trying to use a session.AddFlash method to save an error, then do 302 redirect back to the registration form and display the error.

I set up a session store:

```
package web

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

var sessionStore = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(sessionSecret))
```

Then my handlers look like this:

```
package web

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func registerForm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := sessionStore.Get(r, "mysession")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    data := map[string]interface{}{}
    log.Print("Flashes: ")
    log.Print(session.Flashes())
    if flashes := session.Flashes(); len(flashes) > 0 {
        data["error"] = flashes[0]
    }

    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("web/templates/register.html.tmpl")
    tmpl.Execute(w, data)
}

func register(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := sessionStore.Get(r, "mysession")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    r.ParseForm()
    username := r.Form["username"][0]
    password := r.Form["password"][0]

    if UserExists(username) {
        log.Print("Username already taken")
        session.AddFlash("Username already taken")
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/web/register", http.StatusFound)
        return
    }

    _, err = CreateUser(username, password)
    log.Print(err)

    if err != nil {
        session.AddFlash(err.Error())
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/web/register", http.StatusFound)
        return
    }

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/web/login", http.StatusFound)
}
```

By adding logs I can see that UserExists returns true therefor a flash message should be added however after redirection to the form handler there is no flash message saved in the session.

Comment: From code above, AddFlash method is used twice once inside if UserExists and 2nd inside if error is not nil....AddFlash inside UserExists will be executed in case if UserExists returns true... since you mentioned that UserExists is returning false.....AddFlash inside that if will not be called....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gorilla web toolikit: len(session.Flashes()) is 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219364/gorilla-web-toolikit-lensession-flashes-is-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to save the session before you redirect.

`session.Save(r, w)`

http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions#Session.Save